# Why is my HelloWorld program not compiling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I have been following a HelloWorld tutorial on how to create a basic iphone app using xcode4 and objective C. When I tried to run it errors from an automated class I had not so much as touched sprang up. Seeing as all the errors are within a complex class I've not edited I'm completly at a loss as to what's gone wrong. I accidently typed something in there at some point but undid it right away.

```
Warning: incomplete implementation
Error: Property Implementation must have it's declaration in interface "HelloWorldAppDelegate"
Error: No declaration of property 'window' found in interface
Warning: method definition for changeTheTextOnLabel not found


#import "HelloWorldAppDelegate.h"

#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

@implementation HelloWorldAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize viewController=_viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sounds like your interface doesn't contain a `window` property.

Comment: @George:  Make that an answer, because it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your HelloWorldAppDelegate.h file this appears

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

I'd also double check that in your .XIB file that the window outlet is hooked up.